# Calculate average age based on condition on age column in python

Tags: python, r

I have a R code that i am struggling to translate in python. Please help

```
df$age[(df$age < 18)] <- mean(df$age[(df$age >= 18) & (df$age <=30)],na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Unclear. Do you need help understanding what that R does? In this case should be tagged with R, not Python. Or do you know what it does, and you want to know how to do the same in Python? In this case, just tell us what the code does instead of relying on us knowing both Python and R. Also, show your relevant Python code, particularly your data structures. E.g., are you using plain lists, or numpy or pandas?

Comment: df is a dataframe which has a column age. I can use either numpy or pandas. The code i have pasted is from R which i am trying to convert into python

Comment: The R code calculates mean of users where age is > 18 and < 30 and then assigns to all users where the age is less than 18

Comment: so `df$age` means `df['age']` or `df.age`

Comment: age is a column in dataframe df. So df.age

Comment: I tried this but didn't work df[df.age > 18 and df.age < 30].mean()

Comment: `df['age']` and `df.age` gives the same.

Comment: yes they are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I added `None` in data to get `NaN` in `DataFrame`

---

Probably

```
df.age[(df.age < 18)] = df.age[(df.age >= 18) & (df.age <= 30)].mean()
```

Working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'age': [6, 4, 18, 21, 30, 45, None]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
print('---')

df.age[(df.age < 18)] = df.age[(df.age >= 18) & (df.age <= 30)].mean()

print(df)
print('---')
```

Result

```
    age
0   6.0
1   4.0
2  18.0
3  21.0
4  30.0
5  45.0
6   NaN
---
    age
0  23.0
1  23.0
2  18.0
3  21.0
4  30.0
5  45.0
6   NaN
---
```

Comment: I am sorry i didn't mention but this column has na's as well. How to ignore those while calculating mean

Comment: `mean()` as default has `skipna=True`. I tried with `age: [None, ...]` (it gives `NaN` in data) and it works (no error message) but I don't know what you expect.